# Any way to correctly make weekly time series line chart in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to make a linear chart that visualizes the product's export and sales activity by using weekly base data. Basically, I want to use this data to see how the exporting number of different commodities is changing along with weekly time base data. I could able to aggregate data for making a line chart for the export trends of different commodities for top-5 counties, but the resulted plot in my attempt didn't make my expected output. Can anyone point me out how to make this right? Is there any better way to make a product export trend line chart using `matplotlib` or `seaborn` in python? Can anyone suggest a possible better way of doing this? Any thoughts

**my current attempt**

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import calendar

url = 'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/adamFlyn/e9ad428a266eccb5dc38b4cee7084372/raw/cfcbe9cf0ed19ada6a4ea409644db7414de9c87f/sales_df.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(url)
df.drop(columns=['Unnamed: 0'], inplace=True)

df_grp = df.groupby(['weekEndingDate','country', 'commodity'])['weeklyExports'].sum().unstack().reset_index()
df_grp = df_grp .fillna(0)

for c in df_grp[['FCF_Beef', 'FCF_Pork']]:
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(7, 4), dpi=144)
    
    df_grp_new = df_grp .groupby(['country', 'weekEndingDate'])[c].sum().unstack().fillna(0)
    df_grp_new = df_grp_new .T
    df_grp_new.drop([col for col, val in df_grp_new .sum().iteritems() if val < 1000], axis=1, inplace=True)
    for col in df_grp_new.columns:
        sns.lineplot(x='WeekEndingDate', y='weekly export', ci=None, data=df_grp_new, label=col)
    ax.relim()
    ax.autoscale_view()
    ax.xaxis.label.set_visible(False)
    plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1., 1), loc='upper left')
    plt.ylabel('weekly export')
    plt.margins(x=0)
    plt.title(c)
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.grid(True)
    plt.show()
    plt.close()
```

but these attempts didn't make my expected output. Essentially, I want to see how weekly export of different commodities like beef and pork for different countries by weekly base time series. Can anyone suggest to me what went wrong in my code? How can I get a desirable line chart by using the above data? Any idea?

**desired output**

here is the example desired plots (just style) that I want to make in my attempt:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plenty of ways to do it.  If you make your time column into datetime seaborn will handle formatting the axis for you.

You could use a facetgrid to split by commodity, or if you want finer control over the individual charts plot them using lineplot, filtering the df by the commodity prior.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import calendar

url = 'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/adamFlyn/e9ad428a266eccb5dc38b4cee7084372/raw/cfcbe9cf0ed19ada6a4ea409644db7414de9c87f/sales_df.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(url)
df.drop(columns=['Unnamed: 0'], inplace=True)

df['weekEndingDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['weekEndingDate'])

# sns.set(rc={'figure.figsize':(11.7,8.27)})
g = sns.FacetGrid(df, col='commodity', height=8, sharex=False, sharey=False, legend_out=True)
g.map_dataframe(sns.lineplot, x='weekEndingDate',y='weeklyExports', hue='country', ci=None)
g.add_legend()
```

[image: Chart]

Comment: can we rescale y axis so make plots looks nice?

Comment: Sorry I realized I missed that, yeah sharey=False should do it. I updated the answer. You do have some  outliers in the data, specifically in the pork chart - you could drop that or use some other scaling method on the data to reduce how far off that one is.

Comment: your approach is rather simple, that's nice. Can we reduce the time length, so the weekly trend of export item is more visible to read? Plus, can we make plot where `weeklyExport` and `outstandingSales` for top 3 countries? I tried of grouping like `df.groupby(['weekEndingDate','country', 'commodity'])['weeklyExports', 'outstandingSales'].sum().unstack().reset_index()` but not able to make meaningful plot? Could you show how can we do this? Thank you :)

Comment: Maybe mark this as solved and ask another question.,

Comment: will do, but what I am asking is still based on this question, just a little tweak I am thinking. Plus, here I want to see how each country is sensitive to export different commodities, so do you think we can have a better solution than the current one? Thanks!

Comment: @Adam You should try to be more specific in your original question going forward.  If you  keep expanding it after people have answered they may not want to continue answering.